# What is "type '{}'"?

Tags: types, typescript

In TypeScript, what exactly is `type '{}'` and how does it relate to other built-in types?

For example, the last line of the following example gives `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'number'`, and I am not completely clear on what `type {}` is in this context, or indeed how it comes about:

```
// A function taking no arguments and returning T
type NoArgsFn<T> = () => T;

// An instance of NoArgsFn<number>
function get_the_answer(): number {
  return 42;
}

// Call the supplied function and return its value
function call<T, Fn extends NoArgsFn<T>>(fn: Fn): T {
  return fn();
}

// Expect this to be equivalent to `let the_answer: number = 42', but
// instead get "Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'number'"
let the_answer: number = call(get_the_answer);
```

Comment: A good question, as it isn't clear how `{}` comes about in the example. However, I don't believe you need the `Fn` generic type, and this might relate to the lack of a resolution of `T` to `number`.

Comment: That's right, thanks. If I get rid of `Fn`, the error goes away. That said, I would still like to understand what `type {}` is and why it shows up here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does {} mean in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60381643/what-does-mean-in-typescript)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### `type {}`

Consider the object type `{ id: number, name: string }`, which represents a 2-field object. Legal values of this type include `{ id: 1, name: "Foo" }` and `{ id: 2, name: "Bar" }`.

The type object `{}` represents a 0-field object. The *only* legal value of this type is an empty object: `{}`.

So the *value* `{ id: 1, name: "Foo" }` is of *type* `{ id: number, name: string }`, and the *value* `{}` (i.e. an empty object) is of *type* `{}`.

### The error

The error seems to be a bug in the TypeScript compiler (I submitted an issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8411)). It fails to infer the type arguments in the call to `call`. You can work around this by explicitly specifying the type arguments:

```
let the_answer: number = call<number, NoArgsFn<number>>(get_the_answer);
```

But it's simpler and more straightforward to use a single type argument instead, as @NitzanTomer suggested:

```
function call<T>(fn: NoArgsFn<T>): T {
  return fn();
}
```

**EDIT:** I issue I submitted was closed as a duplicate of [#7234](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234) which is to be fixed before the release of TypeScript 2.0.

Comment: I think it’s worth noting that the compiler inferring a type of `{}` is not necessarily *its* error. Consider `f<a>(one: a, two: a)` called with `f({foo: 2}, {bar: 'thing'})`—the inference would be `{foo:number}|{bar:string}` which is `{}` (nothing in common).

Comment: I downvoted this answer, because it is incorrect: `const test: {} = true;` this is type correct.

Comment: The book _Effective TypeScript_ by Dan Vanderkam says, "The `{}` type consists of all values except `null` and `undefined`." If I write the code in Bart Louwer's comment, eslint says, "Don't use `{}` as a type. `{}` actually means "any non-nullish value"."

Answer (score 5):

You need to have your call function like this:

```
function call<T>(fn: NoArgsFn<T>): T {
    return fn();
}
```

In your original `call` function you had 2 generic types which you did not pass when calling the function and the compiler failed to infer what types they are.

---

#### Edit

Type `{}` is an object literal (as far as I'm aware), and so you can face the same error like this:

```
var o = {};
var n: number = o; // Error: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

I'm not exactly sure why the compiler inferred that the function returns `{}` in your example.

Comment: Thanks, but what *exactly* is `type '{}'`? (I'd also like to understand *why* the inference is failing, but we can tackle that separately.)

Comment: @NPE check my revised answer

Comment: I've been trying to read the specs in a way to justify this behaviour, but [the section on Type inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3117-type-inference) is a bit dense.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, `{}` casts directly to a hash map like usage.  You can only use keyed properties, versus the dot notation.

```
var o:{} = {}
```

should be equivalent to

```
var o:{[key:string]:any} = {}
```

So

```
o.x = 5; //fails
```

But

```
o['x'] = 5; //succeeds
```

Comment: That sounds interesting. Do you have any references for your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The `{}` is a type that can be assigned anything except `null` and `undefined` (=*non-[nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish)* value).

It does NOT represent an object literal without properties. If you wanted that use something like `Record<PropertyKey, never>` instead.

```
let value: {};

value = 5;
value = "Hello World";
value = ["banana", "apple", "orange"];
value = () => true;

value = null;
//~~~ Type 'null' is not assignable to type '{}'.
value = undefined;
//~~~ Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{}'.
```

[TypeScript Playgrond](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAbghsCuIBcEDeBfA3AKG7BIEAvBAKw76LEQBEAFiMMAPYQDuzATsACY0VwqJANo0ARjAB2UmDQA0tGAAcloebS5SA5iBoBdAQWoAKAJTEAfBDCdEOPIMIlJ8JjgD07gH4%20IAFQBPJUIAchcmEIgASwBnCElmSBgYmKitaTFQa1YwINCMEIA6ByMSeEkeEAAzKMkQHg9vX0DgiBDyypq6nkjY%20MSIZNT0mEzCMBy8toLioA)