# TypeScript 2: Remove item from 2-field object

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a 2-field object like this

```
{ id: number, name: string }
```

...and want to remove the `name` item.

How do I accomplish that in TypeScript? I've tried using filter, delete etc but all I get is

```
TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

I think this relates to this question [What is "type '{}'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967176/what-is-type) but I need help to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider :

```
let x : { id: number, name?: string } = {id: 1, name: 'foo'};
```

You can simply use delete:

```
delete x.name;
console.log(x); // {id: 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! This lead me to a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230325/how-to-type-redux-state-in-typescript-to-create-new-state-without-item