# What does "observable<{}[]>" mean?

Tags: rxjs, angularfire2

[image: Visual Studio Code when hovering over method]

Can anyone tell me what `Observable<{}[]>` here means?

Comment: `{ }[ ]` stands for an array of empty objects. In other words the Observable emits arrays of empty objects. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967176/what-is-type

Answer (score 0):

So this doesn't show up as an unanswered question anymore, I'll post martin's answer here:

> `{}[]` stands for an array of empty objects. In other words the
>   Observable emits arrays of empty objects.
>   [stackoverflow.com/questions/36967176/what-is-type](http://%7B%20%7D[%20]%20stands%20for%20an%20array%20of%20empty%20objects.%20In%20other%20words%20the%20Observable%20emits%20arrays%20of%20empty%20objects.%20See%20stackoverflow.com/questions/36967176/what-is-type)

Comment: Because it is the correct answer, but it was already in the comments and I don't want to take credit for it.