# Why is type SFC<AnchorProps> not assignable to type SFC<{}>?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The following code throws an error when it’s compiled by TypeScript.

```js
import React, { SFC } from "react"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { HashLink } from "react-router-hash-link"
import MarkdownToJSX from "markdown-to-jsx"

interface AnchorProps {
  baseUrl: string
  relativeUrl: string
  href: string
}

const Anchor: SFC<AnchorProps> = function(props) {
  /*
  FYI, props.baseUrl and props.relativeUrl is used by code I didn’t include in
  this example to keep things simple.
  */
  if (
    props.href.match(/^http(s)?:\/\//) ||
    props.href.match(/^mailto:/) ||
    props.href.match(/^tel:/)
  ) {
    return (
      <a href={props.href} rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
        {props.children}
      </a>
    )
  } else if (props.href.match(/^#/)) {
    return (
      <HashLink to={props.href} smooth>
        {props.children}
      </HashLink>
    )
  } else {
    return <Link to={props.href}>{props.children}</Link>
  }
}

const Markdown = function() {
  return (
    <MarkdownToJSX
      options={{
        overrides: {
          a: {
            component: Anchor,
            props: {
              baseUrl: "/privacy-guides",
              relativeUrl: "",
            },
          },
        },
      }}
    >
      # This is [markdown](markdown)
    </MarkdownToJSX>
  )
}

export default Markdown
```

```sh
/Users/sunknudsen/Sites/sunknudsen/sunknudsen-website/src/Test.tsx
TypeScript error in /Users/sunknudsen/Sites/sunknudsen/sunknudsen-website/src/Test.tsx(40,13):
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<MarkdownProps>): Markdown', gave the following error.
    Type 'FunctionComponent<AnchorProps>' is not assignable to type 'string | SFC<{}> | ComponentClass<{}, any>'.
      Type 'FunctionComponent<AnchorProps>' is not assignable to type 'SFC<{}>'.
        Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
          Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'PropsWithChildren<AnchorProps>'.
            Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is missing the following properties from type 'AnchorProps': baseUrl, relativeUrl, href
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: MarkdownProps, context?: any): Markdown', gave the following error.
    Type 'FunctionComponent<AnchorProps>' is not assignable to type 'string | SFC<{}> | ComponentClass<{}, any>'.
      Type 'FunctionComponent<AnchorProps>' is not assignable to type 'SFC<{}>'.  TS2769

    38 |         overrides: {
    39 |           a: {
  > 40 |             component: Anchor,
       |             ^
    41 |             props: {
    42 |               baseUrl: "/privacy-guides",
    43 |               relativeUrl: "",
```

I don’t understand why.

Comment: Is this question specific to particular libraries like React?  If so, then it should probably be tagged as such.  If not, then please consider editing the above code to be a [mcve] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE to demonstrate the issue and only the issue you have.  Right now there are some missing type definitions (`ReactNode`, etc).

Comment: I'm guessing that this is because `FunctionComponent<P>` is a function type where `P` appears in contravariant position, so therefore it's not covariant, i.e. `FunctionComponent<B>` is not a subtype of `FunctionComponent<A>` when `B` is a subtype of `A`. But I do not know about the React types used in this code, so I don't know whether that's a complete answer.

Comment: That line is a [call signature](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/callable).  You can consider `(a: A) => B` a shorthand form of `{ (a: A): B }`; the latter form allows you to add other properties.

Comment: Man you guys are good. I don't understand half of the terms you refer to and I’ve been coding for 15 years. I’m a newbie to TypeScript though.

Comment: A React functional component is just a function that takes props and returns a react element. Function parameters act contravariantly.. so you get the error, but i'm sure jcalz will soon answer it :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I'm not too familiar with React, and without the [mcve] I won't answer the question since I like to reproduce things in [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org). Might be as simple as an import statement but I'm not inclined to spend the time at the moment.

Comment: I'm happy to chat about stuff but I'm not sure I feel 100% comfortable moving to a non-public forum; maybe SO chat function on this issue would suffice?  If I can trigger it...

Comment: @jcalz The chat can work for sure if we can get it to fire.

Comment: It's $CURRENT_YEAR and the migrate-to-chat functionality is still not available to non-mods with a button push

Comment: @jcalz Short story, I’m a developer and a tech entrepreneur. I love learning how things work, but I’m spending way too much time figuring some of this TypeScript stuff out. Would love see if you are open to some teaching/contracting. If we can’t get the chat working, feel free to send me an email. If you prefer not, totally understand. Privacy is everything to me.

Comment: @sunknudsen Where in the example are you trying to assign `Anchor` to something?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin These components can get pretty complicated for code blocks... What’s the best way for me to help you guys help me? Looked at JSFiddle but it doesn’t appear to support TypeScript + JSX... Feels like setting up a git repo is overkill.

Comment: @sunknudsen Create an example that, when I paste that example into my local text editor, will show the error. It's OK if that example needs me to install `@types/react` locally. As is, when I paste your example into my local text editor, there is no error. A good example is no more than about 20 lines of code.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Done, let me know if my edit helps. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a limitation of the `markdown-to-jsx` type definitions.

Specifically, The `MarkdownToJSX.options.overrides` is of type `ComponentOverride`, and the `ComponentOverride` is of this type:

```
export type ComponentOverride = string | React.ComponentClass | React.SFC | {
    component: string | React.ComponentClass | React.SFC;
    props?: any;
};
```

That type does not let you pass a generic parameter to `React.SFC`, which means that it takes its default generic parameter:

```
type SFC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;
```

That default generic parameter is an empty object `{}`.

Since your code is trying to assign an `AnchorProps` type to an empty object type, the compiler is complaining.

Whether this is going to be a problem at runtime depends on how the underlying JavaScript works at runtime. It *might* be fine to cast like this:

```
const Markdown = function() {
  return (
    <MarkdownToJSX
      options={{
        overrides: {
          a: {
            component: Anchor,
            props: {
              baseUrl: "/privacy-guides",
              relativeUrl: ""
            }
            // We have tested that this works at runtime,
            // we we know more than the compiler knows.
          } as ComponentOverride
        }
      }}
    >
      # This is [markdown](markdown)
    </MarkdownToJSX>
  );
};
```

Comment: How easy is would it be to fix the type definitions? See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/34408#issuecomment-590475105

Comment: I'm pretty sure my `any` suggestion is pretty naive.

Comment: It would be easier to cast for now. The type definitions are definitely fixable but doing that would require both time and knowledge. Updating the types to make them generic would require understanding the underlying JavaScript to make sure the types reflect what is happening at runtime.

Comment: I confirm casting works... but that’s a bit of a hack right?

Comment: The JS side of things was never broken btw, but somehow after a dependency update, my `//@ts-ignore` patch stopped working.

Comment: @sunknudsen It is a bit of a hack but only a *bit* of a hack. It's reasonably common for `npm` packages to have incomplete type definitions. The pragmatic workaround is to cast (with a comment) when you know more than the compiler knows. When you have the time/knowledge to update the type definitions, do that locally first and then submit a pull request. Casting is certainly less of a hack than using `@ts-ignore` is. The cast has to be at least reasonable (e.g. casting to `Date` will not work without additional persuasion.)