# How can I make ComponentOverride generic?

Tags: typescript

The following [type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/markdown-to-jsx/index.d.ts) for [markdown-to-jsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx) are not generic enough which results in issues such as the following. See 
[Why is type SFC<AnchorProps> not assignable to type SFC<{}>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60382399/why-is-type-sfcanchorprops-not-assignable-to-type-sfc)

```sh
/Users/sunknudsen/Sites/sunknudsen/sunknudsen-website/src/Test.tsx
TypeScript error in /Users/sunknudsen/Sites/sunknudsen/sunknudsen-website/src/Test.tsx(40,13):
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<MarkdownProps>): Markdown', gave the following error.
    Type 'FunctionComponent<AnchorProps>' is not assignable to type 'string | SFC<{}> | ComponentClass<{}, any>'.
      Type 'FunctionComponent<AnchorProps>' is not assignable to type 'SFC<{}>'.
        Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
          Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'PropsWithChildren<AnchorProps>'.
            Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is missing the following properties from type 'AnchorProps': baseUrl, relativeUrl, href
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: MarkdownProps, context?: any): Markdown', gave the following error.
    Type 'FunctionComponent<AnchorProps>' is not assignable to type 'string | SFC<{}> | ComponentClass<{}, any>'.
      Type 'FunctionComponent<AnchorProps>' is not assignable to type 'SFC<{}>'.  TS2769

    38 |         overrides: {
    39 |           a: {
  > 40 |             component: Anchor,
       |             ^
    41 |             props: {
    42 |               baseUrl: "/privacy-guides",
    43 |               relativeUrl: "",
```

How can I make `ComponentOverride` generic? Have to admit type definitions blow my mind. I see this questions as a learning opportunity for me and others. Spent all day trying to figure it out.

```js
// Type definitions for markdown-to-jsx 6.9
// Project: https://probablyup.github.io/markdown-to-jsx
// Definitions by: Elizabeth Craig <https://github.com/ecraig12345>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped
// TypeScript Version: 2.8

import * as React from 'react';

export default class Markdown extends React.Component<MarkdownProps> { }

export interface MarkdownProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
    options?: MarkdownOptions;
    // React.ReactNode contains both null and undefined
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-null-undefined-union
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}

export type ComponentOverride = string | React.ComponentClass | React.SFC | {
    component: string | React.ComponentClass | React.SFC;
    props?: any;
};

export interface MarkdownOptions {
    /** Force all input strings to use block layout. */
    forceBlock?: boolean;

    /** Force all input strings to use inline layout. */
    forceInline?: boolean;

    /** Override representation of any HTML tag or custom component. */
    overrides?: {
        // As of 6.9.3, these tags are the only ones automatically generated by markdown-to-jsx.
        a?: ComponentOverride;
        br?: ComponentOverride;
        button?: ComponentOverride;
        code?: ComponentOverride;
        del?: ComponentOverride;
        div?: ComponentOverride;
        em?: ComponentOverride;
        footer?: ComponentOverride;
        input?: ComponentOverride;
        h1?: ComponentOverride;
        h2?: ComponentOverride;
        h3?: ComponentOverride;
        h4?: ComponentOverride;
        h5?: ComponentOverride;
        h6?: ComponentOverride;
        hr?: ComponentOverride;
        img?: ComponentOverride;
        ol?: ComponentOverride;
        p?: ComponentOverride;
        pre?: ComponentOverride;
        span?: ComponentOverride;
        strong?: ComponentOverride;
        sub?: ComponentOverride;
        sup?: ComponentOverride;
        table?: ComponentOverride;
        tbody?: ComponentOverride;
        td?: ComponentOverride;
        th?: ComponentOverride;
        thead?: ComponentOverride;
        tr?: ComponentOverride;
        ul?: ComponentOverride;
        /** In addition to HTML tags, you can specify a custom component name which can be used within markdown text. */
        [key: string]: ComponentOverride | undefined;
    };

    /** Custom React.createElement behavior. */
    createElement?: <P extends {}>(
        type: React.SFC<P> | React.ComponentClass<P> | string,
        // This typing is copied from React
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-null-undefined-union
        props?: React.Attributes & P | null,
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-null-undefined-union
        ...children: React.ReactNode[]) => React.ReactElement<P>;

    /** Custom function to generate an HTML id from headings. */
    slugify?: (text: string) => string;
}

export function compiler(markdown: string, options?: MarkdownOptions): JSX.Element;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good for you for learning TypeScript. Here is a generic version of `ComponentOverride` for you.

```
export type ComponentOverride<TProps = any, TState = any> = 
  string | 
  React.ComponentClass<TProps, TState> | 
  React.SFC<TProps> | 
  {
    component: string | React.ComponentClass<TProps, TState> | React.SFC<TProps>;
    props?: TProps;
  };
```

You could use it like this:

```
const Markdown = function() {
  const anchorOverride: ComponentOverride<AnchorProps> = {
    component: Anchor,
    props: {
      baseUrl: "/privacy-guides",
      relativeUrl: "",
      href: ""
    }
  };

  return (
    <MarkdownToJSX
      options={{
        overrides: {
          a: anchorOverride
        }
      }}
    ></MarkdownToJSX>
  );
};
```

See also: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: Thanks for your help Shaun. Is `TProps = any` a type parameter default?

Comment: Yes. `TProps = any` makes `any` the default value of `TProps`.

Comment: Would you happen to know where this is explained in the docs? Can’t find it... but I did find related PRs such as https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13487.

Comment: @sunknudsen The version 2.3 release notes explain generic defaults here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults

Comment: Suggested an edit. Let me know if I missed something. Thanks so much for your help! Will submit a PR to DefinitelyTyped.

Comment: Hey Shaun. Had suggested an edit that used the type inference properties of generics vs long form such as `ComponentOverride<AnchorProps>`. Looks like it was refused. Did you have a chance to peak at it? I didn’t know of another way to send it to you as the edit was too long for comments (somehow I thought you would review it). Would have loved to get your feedback.

Comment: @sunknudsen I rejected the edits because they removed the usage example. The usage example shows how to maintain type safety. In contrast, assigning to the `a` inline removes type safety because the `overrides` will all have props and state as `any`. The edits changed the props type to `any`. I did however keep your typing parameters for `TState`.