# Upgrading @types/react to 18.0.0 gives no overload matches this call on React.createElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

In my code I just want to use a generic type `MyProps` and my function accepts a parameter of ComponentClass. This started throwing the error

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'ComponentClass<MyProps, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | FunctionComponent<{}> | ComponentClass<{}, any>'.
      Type 'ComponentClass<MyProps, any>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<{}, any>'.
        Types of property 'getDerivedStateFromProps' are incompatible.
          Type 'GetDerivedStateFromProps<MyProps, any> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'GetDerivedStateFromProps<{}, any> | undefined'.
            Type 'GetDerivedStateFromProps<MyProps, any>' is not assignable to type 'GetDerivedStateFromProps<{}, any>'.
              Types of parameters 'nextProps' and 'nextProps' are incompatible.
                Type 'Readonly<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<MyProps>'.
```

This happened only after upgrading to @types/react  to 18.0.0

I want to know **what broke this flow and how to fix it.**
Most suggestions are around downgrading to v17 but I don't want that, I want to upgrade my app to v18.
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60382399/why-is-type-sfcanchorprops-not-assignable-to-type-sfc) but it doesn't explain what caused this error or proper solutions for this.
This is a minimum reproducible code:

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
render() {
    return this.createElement(Text);
}

createElement<MyProps>(component:ComponentClass<MyProps>) {
    return React.createElement(component);
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Update: I was able to fix the issue by modifying as `createElement<MyProps extends {}>`
still not sure what has changed here or if this was an old issue and popped up only now. Any help appreciated!

Comment: How is `MyProps` defined when you use it?

Comment: I tried by passing TextProps from @types/react-native