# How to Create a Mixin in Angular11 with ESLint

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mixins, angular11

In my **Angular9** and **Angular10** projects I was able to create `mixins` using the below steps from [Harnessing the power of Mixins in Angular](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/harnessing-the-power-of-mixins-in-angular-f2faa432add2) blog

**constructor.mixin.ts**

```
export type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
```

**my-mixin.mixin.ts**

```
import {Constructor} from './constructor.mixin';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

export const myMixin = <T extends Constructor>(BaseClass: T = class { } as T) =>
  class extends BaseClass {
    title = 'Title in the mixin';
    titleUpdateSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject('');
    title$ = this.typedTitleSubject$.asObservable();
  };
```

This worked fine till I updated angular following the steps in [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/?v=10.0-11.0)

After a successful change from `TSLint` to `ESLint` following [Migrating an Angular CLI project from Codelyzer and TSLint](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint#migrating-an-angular-cli-project-from-codelyzer-and-tslint) and running linting (`npx ng lint my-project-name --fix`) I receive the below error

> 1:29  error  Don't use `{}` as a type. `{}` actually means "any non-nullish value".
>
> - If you want a type meaning "any object", you probably want `Record<string, unknown>` instead.
> - If you want a type meaning "any value", you probably want `unknown` instead  @typescript-eslint/ban-types

The error is being thrown on the line `export type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;`

My problem is how I can refactor this line to satisfy `typescript`. Unfortunately I am unable to find an answer with my use case e.g in [TypeScript '{}' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62397594/typescript-type) is about how to type non `nullish` value.

Comment: any solution here?

Comment: @MordechaiDror `export type Constructor<T = Record<string, unknown>> = new (...args: any[]) => T;` is what I currently use

Comment: if I use it like this I get ts compilation error `Argument of type 'typeof (Anonymous class)' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Constructor<Record<string, unknown>>'` in place of using mixin