# TypeScript not enforcing generics extend?

Tags: typescript

I have this interface:

```js
export default interface Cacheable {
}
```

and then this one that extends it:

```js
import Cacheable from "./cacheable.js";

export default interface Coin extends Cacheable{
    id: string;  // bitcoin
    symbol: string; // btc
    name: string; // Bitcoin
}
```

Now, I have a Cache object with a `getData` method as such:

```js
public async getData<T extends Cacheable>(key: string): Promise<T | T[]> {
```

Now I can get cached coin data:

```js
const coins = (await cache.getData('coins.json')) as Coin[];
```

What bothers me, is that I can still use the generic getData method with types that *are not extending* `Cachable`. For exmaple, TS compiles the following successfully against my expectations:

```js
const num: number = (await cache.getData('coins.json')) as number
```

What am I missing? Why am I not restricted to use only types that are `Cacheable` with the generic `getData` method?

Comment: `as` literally means I know better. Typescript and typesafety are not equal things. The proper usage should be `getData<TypeOfData>(..)` instead of `as T`

Comment: If that's the actual definition of `Cacheable` then the code is working entirely as expected. Remember the type system is structural. Given that, a type that declares no members implies no restrictions. @antokhio, explicitly type arguments is typically suspect except in very rare cases.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you seem to misunderstand:

- When using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) TypeScript doesn't *really* care about constraints or type annotations. You override what the compiler infers.

  Just one side note:

  > TypeScript only allows type assertions which convert to a more specific or less specific version of a type. This rule prevents “impossible” coercions like `const x = "hello" as number;`.
- TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/structural-typing). In your example this means that the `Cachable` interface is equal to the type `{}`. The [`{}` type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967176/what-is-type) seems to be causing a lot of confusion altough it's quite simple actually:

  Everything is assignable to `{}` except `null` or `undefined`. That's the reason you don't get a generic constraint error with `number`.

If you changed the definition of `Cacheable` to something like...

```
export interface Cacheable {
  thisProperty: "makesTypeNumberUnassignable";
}

interface Coin extends Cacheable {
  id: string;
  symbol: string;
  name: string;
}

declare function getData<T extends Cacheable>(key: string): Promise<T | T[]>;
```

... you get the according assertion error.

```
const num = (await getData("coins.json")) as number;
//          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Conversion of type 'Cacheable | Cacheable[]' to type 'number' may be a mistake ...
```