# Typescript JSON type not working properly (recursive type definition problem?)

Tags: typescript, json-value, recursive-type

I created a legit JSONValue type with some recursive logic. I've tried everything and read a lot of documentation, still don't understand why this not works as expected (the compiler doesn't complain when I define the object, but **it complains when I try to use it**!).

Can anybody give me some insights here? What I'm doing it wrong?

```
type JSONPrimitive = {} | null | undefined // any primitive, null or undefined
type JSONObject = { [k: string]: JSONValue }
type JSONArray = JSONValue[]
type JSONValue = JSONArray | JSONObject | JSONPrimitive

let myObject: JSONValue = {
  someString: 'it complains',
  someObj: {
    anotherString: 'why?'
  },
  someNull: null
}

console.log( myObject.someString )
                      // ^ Error here `Property 'someString' does not exist on type '{}`
```

On the last console log the compiler says: `Property 'someString' does not exist on type '{}`

[Try it on the Ts Playground (error at line 17)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false&alwaysStrict=false&target=2#code/PTAEAEGcBcCcEsDG0ByBXANhgwgCwKaIDWkAXKAGYCGGk+AUCBNFbAOb7TkCiAygEwAGAIwBWevWgBPAA75QAKV4B5FAAUEAW3jR4AN3kBeUAG8AvqAA+oAHaYMV0GhsATfBXg38L0Eyo2pUBktHX18ABpbe1AAe1gnV3dPb0lZeSVVZQAjACtCaFBjE1AAbSJyGAQbNgBdcgyUADUaNHkzVLlFFRQAQVhYKkDjBuaMVpKajvTu0dbCrtU+gcDrBuy85EcGjXhtXQMJDE5QTSl1-PqZlqNTelBQSBjNfF44TzZyAHIdUEQnmQwVE8kE+4TuDye+HW5BM4Pu-hi0AIsFeVQ+oE+AHdcFIAPyfcFmMH3R7PdBYch2LD0dr0P42R5HAB0GBibAAFCczrl8kzSS83tVQABKCSMABUoHB0k60BiMgAKml5lSHNZnG4PF4fNZzFL7jL5HKZOdNkVSuVKu86qBjaaChZpcrjbMbsalZ1rHaecg7uLgEA).

===
EDIT, another example:
If I add some function like this, the compiler complains, so what is the point here? How can I use this:

```
logMyObjectNested(myObject)
// This is totally fine...

function logMyObjectNested( objParam: JSONValue ) {
  console.log( objParam.someObj )
                        // ^ it complains ...
}
```

Comment: I can't exactly tell why TypeScript behaves that way, but the problems are reproducible by creating an object with type `{}`. You should avoid using`{}` as a type.

Comment: But I read on the documentation that `{}` stand for any primitive except `null` or `undefined` right?

Comment: This is definitely not correct, do you have a link to that documentation?

Comment: No I will try to retrieve it (this is a problem I had encountered weeks ago, asking only now), maybe I misread

Comment: `{}` represents any type except `null | undefined` (=any non-nullish type). That's why `{} | null | undefined` looks confusing to me because that should be equal to `any`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967176/what-is-type/77569292#77569292.

Comment: Indeed why it says that it's an error, since it represents any non nullish type it should let me log that string or object right?

Answer (score 0):

It just warns you that the field that you presume to exist does not necessarily exist as per the type declaration. You can convert it to the correct type and you will have no complaints afterwards:

```
type JSONPrimitive = {} | null | undefined // any primitive, null or undefined
type JSONObject = { [k: string]: JSONValue }
type JSONArray = JSONValue[]
type JSONValue = JSONArray | JSONObject | JSONPrimitive

let myObject: JSONValue = {
  someString: 'it complains',
  someObj: {
    anotherString: 'why?'
  },
  someNull: null
}

console.log( (myObject as JSONObject).someString )
```